# Issue with bash command in airflow

Tags: shell, unix, airflow

My objective is to run a native python file, append a log in log file, return OK if command executes successfully and return NOK plus exit 1 if command fails.
The code for the same is,

```
RunDataException = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_data_exception',    
    bash_command= '`python ~/BoulderDash/DataProcessingPipeline/data_exception_pipeline.py 2>&1 | tee -a $(pwd)/BoulderDash_output.log && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK" && exit 1; }`',
    dag=main_dag,
    email_on_failure = True,
    email = 'abc@xyz.com',
    on_failure_callback = throw_error
    )
```

I am getting OK message even when I know from the log in Airflow that the command actually failed.
Interestingly, if I use

```
enter`python ~/BoulderDash/DataProcessingPipeline/data_exception_pipeline.py 2>&1 $(pwd)/BoulderDash_output.log && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK" && exit 1; }`'
```

Here, I have removed | tee -a  . Then it prints NOK that is expected but then my objective of writing into log gets defeated. Please help me with this.

Comment: you can capture return status  using  `$?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 bash_command= '`python ~/BoulderDash/DataProcessingPipeline/data_exception_pipeline.py 2> >(tee -a $(pwd)/BoulderDash_output.log) && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK" && exit 1; }`',
```

Demo:

```
:>:> BoulderDash_output.log 
:>eval 1/0  2> >(tee -a BoulderDash_output.log) && echo "OK" || { echo "NOK"; }
NOK
:>bash: 1/0: No such file or directory

:>cat BoulderDash_output.log 
bash: 1/0: No such file or directory
:>
```